# MUI v5 styled from '@mui/system' vs '@mui/material/styles'

Tags: material-ui

there are two ways to import the styled() function. The docs says that the only difference is the default theme that is used. Does anyone know the difference?

Answer (score 1):

According to their [docs](https://mui.com/system/styled/#import-path)

> You can use the utility coming from the @mui/system package, or if you
> are using @mui/material, you can import it from @mui/material/styles.
> The difference is in the default theme that is used (if no theme is
> available in the React context).

The default theme from @mui/system is very minimal. The default theme from @mui/material/styles is an [enhanced version of the default theme from @mui/system](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/styles/createTheme.js#:%7E:text=const%20systemTheme%20%3D%20systemCreateTheme(options)%3B) that comes with a lot of ready to use predefined properties. If you are interested in a side by side comparison of the two have a look at the [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/default-theme-coparison-o6gld4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) I made.

Comment: As the question clearly mentioned, the docs are a little unclear about this. So sharing some more insights about the differences would be appreciated.

Comment: @HamedSiaban thank you for your feedback. I actually did overlook that the questioner was aware of the use of different default themes mentionend in the docs.